# Example of @DecimalMax.List usage?

Tags: java, validation, annotations

hi.

Can anyone give a meaningful example of `@DecimalMax.List` from `javax.validation.constraints.*` usage? How can a field have several maximum limits?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[All annotations of the package](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/validation/constraints/package-summary.html) have a corresponding `List` annotation. Even constraints such as `@NotNull`.

This allows to use the same annotation for different [validating groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups). With `@DecimalMax.List`, you can set one maximum for one group and another maximum for another group.

Comment: thanks, Wil. I didn't know we may define several check-sets to validate bean for different biz contexts.